# How to make SqlContext.Pipe.Send(string str) flush to SSMS immediately?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I'm using SqlContext.Pipe.Send(string str) to send messages from a SQL/CLR stored procedure, but the message is not displayed in SSMS immediately. How to flush the message to SSMS immediately? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt what @RBarryYoung is saying like this:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"));
sqlCon.Open();

try {
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(String.Format("raiserror('{0}', 0, 0) with nowait", str), sqlCon);
    SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend(sqlCommand);
} finally {
    sqlCon.Close();
}
```

If you want to do this using Send, you can fill the buffer:

```
SqlContext.Pipe.Send(str.PadRight(4000));
SqlContext.Pipe.Send(String.Empty.PadRight(4000));
```

The maximum message length `Send()` can handle is 4000. To fill the buffer you need to send another line with spaces in it. Using 4000 for the second line should ensure it flushes your whole message no matter what's already in the buffer.

The only downside to the second way is you get a blank line between messages, and lots of extra spaces. The first way produces nicer output.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of to do this is to use `RAISERROR` with the `WITH NOWAIT` option.  This will cause all of the the pending text output to flush immediately.  This doesn't have to be a real error or anything, this will work fine:

```
RAISERROR(' ',1,1) WITH NOWAIT;
```

Comment: This method can be used in T-SQL stored procedures, but not in CLR stored procedures. But thank you!